# Rotating a composable not taking up full screen width and height-Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple card which is expected to be rotated to landscape version . The challenge is that i should switch the orientation of the device or activity. So i tried rotating the card 90f and given max width but still it takes the width of the portrait measure only.
[image: please see this output].
I Have passed screen height as the width of the card to take the full space. but its still coming like this.
Why cant i switch orientation? Thats because when i switch orientation the screen flickers because it show window background.

But it is expected to take full screen space. Can any one please help to make this take full screen space when rotated?.

here is my code.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.rotate
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.mycompose.ui.theme.MyComposeTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyComposeTheme {
                val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

                val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
                val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background.copy(.3f)
                ) {
                    RotatingCard(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .rotate(90f)
                            .width(screenHeight)
                            .height(screenWidth)
                            .padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RotatingCard(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "Rotated", fontSize = 24.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is setting **.rotate(90f)**  has rotate your screen 90 degree. your screen is actually rotating but you will see the width of your screen .

You can remove **.rotate(90f)**  and set a specific height for your card instead of using a rotation.

Here is how it look setting **.rotate(50f)**

[image]

Comment: thanks alot for your time.But my question was why dont it take the size specified when rotated? the height is ok . but width should be height of the screen right/
You are right the screen is rotating. But the width is not taking up the space and stick to device width itself

Comment: It is simple

when you are on portrait mode or  landscape mode, width = height and height = width

so the widht will always be the height which will only take the width portion of the app

Comment: Can you please give a working code @Muraino

Comment: what do you want to achieve... do you want to ignore the rotate to 90 degree when the app is rotated

Answer (score 0):

To ensure card occupies the entire space in both the orientation, apply the `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` to the `RotatingCard`.

```
   Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
           color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background.copy(.3f)) {
                    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

                    val isLandScape by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                    } // current screen orientation

                    RotatingCard(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        isLandscape = isLandScape
                    )
                }
```

Instead of rotating the entire card, rotate the content within the card based on the screen orientation.

```
 @Composable
fun RotatingCard(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, isLandscape: Boolean) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Rotated",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.rotate(if (isLandscape) 360f else 0f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FubHg.jpg)

[Potrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2CrT.jpg)

Comment: I cant switch the orientation.  Thts the challenge

Comment: Use a real device instead of an emulator.